# Compiling Qt 4.7.4 With X11 Embed support

Tags: linux, qt

I've just recompiled Qt 4.7.4 on a new machine (issues with Phonon necessitated a full recompile), the issue now being that the X11 embed aspects don't seem to be working. I know that they *have* been working but I can't remember for the life of me what specific configure flag I need to pass in for it to be enabled.

UPDATE: Still getting this issue, I started dumping further info in the execution and it's returning invalid window ID each time. However the previous build of Qt (also 4.7.4, built on the same platform) does work so I'm at somewhat of a loss now. Bounty reopened.

Comment: how do you compile it? It should be enabled by default, if you compile on linux

Comment: What exactly is not working? I compiled Qt 4.7.2 a couple of days ago without specifying anything specific for X11, and xembed seems to be working...

Comment: Well, it fails to embed the window and appears to be unsuccessfully attempting to get the window ID. Compiled with basic flags and then leave it up to Qt to get the rest right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, I removed all configure options and added them back in. I believe using a specific combination of the configure options from -x* causes the issue but I'm not sure *what* combination. If anyone else runs into this issue start from scratch and come back up.